# CASE on Alias Column selected in SubQuery and Alias column in WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two questions.

1. Remove the row WHERE `difference_previous_level` is `0` for the same `time` , which means I don't want to repeat the row with the same time. In the screenshot attached we shouldn't have row no 331 because it has same time as row 332 and `difference_previous_level` is `0` while row 332 should stay here. While `difference_previous_level` and `previous_level` are Alias columns.
   [Image where row 331 should delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soP6j.png)

2. Apply CASE on Alias Column selected in the sub query. I want to apply CASE on `difference_previous_level` WHEN VALUE not `0` THEN `regenzähler` column value, e.g in row no 332, `difference_previous_level` is `2` it should have value `2103` from `Regenzähler`.
   Here is what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT time_time , col_2 AS Regenzähler,  LAG(col_2) OVER (ORDER BY time_time ) AS previous_level,  col_2-LAG(col_2) OVER (ORDER BY time_time ) AS difference_previous_level
FROM  raindata
Order by time_time, difference_previous_level
```

I tried both but error is alias column doesn't exit.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: can you please see the picture attached https://i.stack.imgur.com/soP6j.png , if not then I rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could add a column with LAG for column time_time and then filter out rows with difference_previous_level=0 AND time_time = previous_time_time.

```sql
SELECT t.* FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT time_time , 
        LAG(time_time) OVER (ORDER BY time_time )   AS previous_time_time,
        col_2                                       AS Regenzähler,  
        LAG(col_2) OVER (ORDER BY time_time )       AS previous_level,  
        col_2-LAG(col_2) OVER (ORDER BY time_time ) AS difference_previous_level
    FROM  raindata
) t
WHERE NOT (t.difference_previous_level = 0 AND t.previous_time_time = t.time_time)
ORDER BY t.time_time, t.difference_previous_level
```

2. Try like below:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.*,
    CASE 
        WHEN difference_previous_level <> 0 THEN t.Regenzähler 
        ELSE difference_previous_level
    END AS new_column
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT time_time , 
        LAG(time_time) OVER (ORDER BY time_time )   AS previous_time_time,
        col_2                                       AS Regenzähler,  
        LAG(col_2) OVER (ORDER BY time_time )       AS previous_level,  
        col_2-LAG(col_2) OVER (ORDER BY time_time ) AS difference_previous_level
    FROM  raindata
) t
WHERE NOT (t.difference_previous_level = 0 AND t.previous_time_time = t.time_time)
ORDER BY t.time_time, t.difference_previous_level
```

Comment: how to write same query in Grafana ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not known Grafana.